# Throttling requests in Azure Function Cosmos DB output binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-servicebus-queues

I am building an Azure function that retrieves delta updates from Service Bus and should create/update documents based on that in Cosmos DB.

Currently I am only using the output binding to achieve this, but I am running into 429 errors when I have a lot of updates in the queue, even with 20.000 RU/s.

It looks like I need to throttle the amount of data coming from Bus -> Azure Function -> Cosmos DB. What is the "best practice" way to approach this?

I can only find limited information on this topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic retry to CosmosDb output binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50695921/automatic-retry-to-cosmosdb-output-binding)

Comment: [How to use Azure functions to process high throughput messages](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-azure-functions-to-process-high-throughput-messages-996d05d4ab23/)

Comment: RU/sec are spread across physical partitions (e.g. if you have 5 physical partitions, you're going to see 4K/sec, when allocating 20,000/sec). How many physical partitions do you have? As for "best practice" - there's just no single right answer to that.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I was just wondering what the best practice is to handle the 429 errors coming from the Cosmos DB SDK.  I'm not sure what physical partitions have to do with that. Maybe i failed to describe my question.

Comment: @DeepDave-MT thank you for the links, the output bindings just seem to add a layer on top of the already established retry functionality of Service Bus. I guess for now I will let the Exception bubble to Service Bus and let it handle retrying the 429 errors.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice way to do this in functions would be splitting up your requests in singular functions that do the actual requests which are triggered by a stack or a queue like Azure Storage Queues. Your main function just fills up the queue and you control the parallel execution via. the host.json setting `batchSize`.

Error handling can be achieved natively with poison queues. If an execution (dequeue) failed for example if you throw on a 429, more than 5 times, the message will be moved to a poison queue. You can control the number with the `maxDequeueCount` parameter in the host.json file.

To use and integrate this feature, to avoid too many requests on your CosmosDB, you can adjust the batch size, increase the dequeue count and use are more or less complex pattern to for example sleep a certain amount of time depending on the current dequeue count. The count can be accessed with `context.triggerMetadata.dequeueCount` in JS/TS.

Answer (score -2):

Throttling problem "429 - too many requests" error can be solved using **Azure Logic App** service. As you have asked for the best approach, this is one approach which can solve your issue with less efforts.

Below are some key points you need to take care when using Logic App:

- Limit the number of logic app instances that can run at the same
  time.
- Enable high throughput mode.
- Disable array debatching ("split on") behavior in triggers.
- Refactor actions into smaller logic apps.

Refer: [Handle throttling problems (429 - "Too many requests" errors) in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/handle-throttling-problems-429-errors#logic-app-throttling)

Comment: Using Logic Apps for data processing is a very bad idea. They are neither made for data processing nor for high throughputs.
Logic Apps are for workflow orchestration, not execution of actual things on the data.